# How to calculate the velocity of this body?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, acceleration, distance

> *Graph of a train (the body) is provided which starts from rest. What is the velocity after the train has 10 metres displacement?*

[image]

Thats the only things provided for the question, please help me out here, I find that more variables will be required but the book states that no more variables are required.

The answer key says that the answer is 10 m/s only! I am totally unable to understand how.

Comment: What have you tried?  What equations of motion do you know? (do you have a textbook which discusses this?) .

Comment: I have tried all possible combination of the equations I knew, @CarlWitthoft . The main problem that arises is that there are just too many variable quantities that are unknown, the eqns I tried were the main 3 only, and I think the question is probably to be done using only graphs, as it was in that specific section(By saying that, I mean that possibly, not many eqns of motion are needed to solve this), cheers and please help me if you can :)

Comment: @user47047 The 3 basic equations you used can only be used when the accelration is constant, which here is not the case.

Comment: ya, youre right @Shubham

Comment: But its not really a homework, I'm just doing the questions from the book for enrichment, @jinawee

Comment: You can see what is considered homework here: http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange The word homework isn't used as you would find in a dictionary.

Comment: I hope you get my answer...

Answer (score 1):

We know that $v^2-u^2=2ax$ is valid for constant acceleration. So, what are we waiting for? Lets find how this apply this.

We will use $v^2-u^2=2ax$ for a $very$ small time(or distance) for which we will say acceleration is constant.

$$v_0^2-u_0^2=2a_0x_0$$

$$v_1^2-u_1^2=2a_1x_1$$

$$v_2^2-u_2^2=2a_2x_2$$
$$\cdots$$

$$v_f^2-u_f^2=2a_fx_f$$

Note that $v_0=u_1$, $v_1=u_2$ as the intervals are directly after the time where previous equation was applied.

Add all of them.

$$v_f^2-u_0^2=2(a_0x_0+...a_fx_f)$$

Now look at the graph. Each term in right hand side represents area of the very small part of graph :[image]

Add all rectangles for complete area. Hence, right hand side is twice of area and as initial speed is $0ms^{-1},$ we get, $v_f^2=2\times\text{Area}$

Comment: You can generalize this result.$2\times$ Area under $a-x$ graph is $v^2-u^2$

Comment: whats v-subscript-f ?

Comment: @user47047 Final speed. f stands for final

Comment: So, final speed comes out to be 180 m/ sec ?

Comment: @user47047 It is $v^2$ and hence, answer is $\sqrt{180} m/s$

Answer (score 1):

The work done (per unit mass) after it has traveled a distance $x$ is the area under the acceleration curve between $0$ and $x$. $$W = 6 x - \frac{x^2}{10}$$

This work goes into kinetic energy (per unit mass) which is $K=\frac{1}{2} v^2$. Equating the two will give the velocity as a function of position

$$ v(x) = \sqrt{12 x - \frac{x^2}{5}} $$

### Appendix

Area under acceleration curve $a(x)  = 6 \left(1-\frac{x}{30}\right)$

[image: Sketch]

Area of rectangle$x \, a(x) = 6x-\frac{x^2}{5}$

Area of triangle $\frac{1}{2} x (6-a(x)) = \frac{x^2}{10}$

Total Area $ W = 6x-\frac{x^2}{5} + \frac{x^2}{10} = 6x-\frac{x^2}{10} $

Comment: How did you reach W = 6x - x^2/10 ?

Comment: @user47047 Formula for trapezium area, I guess.

Comment: But we dont have a trapezium here, @Awesome !

Comment: @user47047 He is talking about a general $x$ is between. Just plug in $x=30m$

Comment: @user47047 Its the same area concept as Awesome used, Work is given by mass $times$ the area of the accelration displacement graph(You could, if you want, see it from $W=Fs$, and $F=ma$). Also, any work done on a body goes to change its kinetic energy.

Comment: See appendix in post.

Answer (score 0):

According to the graph, accelration is linearly dependent on displacement. Now, assuming the motion is rectillinear(along a straight line, and quite justified for 30 m displacement of a train).

It is not very difficult to find the equation of this straight line (intercept form).

And then, you'll need some calculus to find velocity $\nu$ in terms of displacement $x$, which involves the following substitution : $$a=\nu\frac{d\nu}{dx}$$

Now transfer $dx$ to the other side and integrate. Try and see if it helps.

Comment: Are you sure we need to use integration, I am only in 9th standard and we havent been taught integration or differentiation yet, and I dont really know how to do it! cheers, Nalin and pls see if any other method exists. :)

Comment: And I also havent been taught Calculus yet :)

Comment: Well, then, you were right, the problem IS difficult.

Comment: Haha, is there no other way you know of ?

Comment: $a=\color\red{v}\dfrac{dv}{dx}$

Comment: @Awesome, sorry I missed that one out. Will edit

Comment: I didnt even understand where that came from @Shubham

Comment: @user47047 How does your textbook derive $v^2-u^2=2aS$?

Comment: Using graphs @Awesome , and is that found in the mathematical derivation ?

Comment: @user47047 Graphs between what exactly?

Comment: @user47047, it won't really make sense if you haven't studied calculus, we'd have to find another way.

Comment: @Shubham An argument can be made using averages and area.

Comment: @Awesome , I'm only getting around 10% of the things you guys are talking about, please try to find a method that a 13 year old can understand :)

Comment: @user47047 You didn't reply to my comment. Which graph did your textbook use? Between speed and time?

Comment: @Awesome , sorry for not replying, but, the book uses a v-t graph and we just find s by the area of trapezium and substitute time to find the 3rd eqn

Comment: Let me write an answer.

Comment: Ok, @Awesome but make sure it's understandable for me :)